# How to exclude some modules from rebuilding on dev env (Angular 5)?

Tags: angular

I'm wondering if it's possible to temporarily exclude some modules which are lazy loaded from a rebuild. Currently I have more than 10 lazy modules and all the time when I change something in my code all chunks start to rebuild and of course it takes time.

So I would like to leave just a couple of modules which I work on and continue to rebuild them in order to have an actual result but the rest can be an old version

I've tried to exclude it in tsconfig.json but it doesn't help

`...
  "types": [ "node" ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "path/to/lazy-module/lazy.module.ts"
  ]`

Comment: What do you mean by `it doesn't help`? excluding them in the `tsconfig.json` should stop transpilation of those modules on every build.

Comment: Unfortunately module is rebuilt as others

Comment: Upgrade to Angular 7 because the compiling speed is a lot better and it caches are lot of the process.

Comment: Yes. I'm going to upgrade it but first wanted to resolve my issue with angular 5. Thanks!